# MSP430 seems to reset intermittently

Tags: msp430, debugging

I'm using the [MSP430F5515](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f5515.pdf) variant. I can't figure out any structured reason for it, but the chip clearly resets itself occasionally - i'm logging data and i put a 'known' string that only prints at startup in the code. I'm thinking it has something to do with my manipulation of the Unified Clock System registers, or maybe something to do with the High/Low side Voltage Supervisor functions (which I'm not changing from their system defaults). I'm pretty sure I don't have any kind of stack-overflow (no pun intended) going on, but one can never really rule that out.

Getting to my question here... are there any register settings one needs to assign explicitly in your MSP430 startup code so that the system does not reset? Is there any diagnostics that I can use to determine for what reason (at least "the last") reset occured. I'm thinking using the MSP430FET-UIF programmer/debugger to halt the processor and look at some register values, though my gut says I can't attach to a running processor without resetting it and loading a new program... Any thoughts / advice would be appreciated...

-Vic

Comment: You say you're running a logger.  Would you care to post the code which should be running while you're taking your logs?  I strongly suspect that you do have some sort of stack overflow/null pointer issue.

Comment: Also, *when* should the system does not reset?  There are lots of ways to reset the micro (or at least make it start from the beginning of your code). Do you want it to continue running when a certain error is triggered? When you switch your program counter to 0x00? When the watchdog timer is triggered? When the reset button is pressed? If you do want one or more of these conditions, what should it do instead if it thinks it's so badly broken that it needs to reset?

Comment: Is there a way to emulate the processor on a computer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To see why you are being RESET you need to check the system rest vector (SYSRSTIV) at address 019Eh and you will be able to see the cause of your reset.  There are many things on a MSP430 that will cause a reset

Answer (score 10):

if the watchdog is enabled make sure you don't have some piece of code that can occasionally take a long time to execute (usually blocking IO).  If there is such code make sure you pet the watchdog during such operations.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the watchdog timer. As far as I remember you need to explicitly disable it during startup, if you do not want to use it.

Comment: Yes, that was the immediate association for me too. And like another answer said, check the reset vector for clues.

Comment: From now on, instead of retriggering or restarting my watchdog timers, I will pet them.  Good answer, by the way.